# remove Page Title

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage

I try to remove page title with addin the "Visible="false"".

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" Visible="false">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
```

but when I add it , it also make the visiblity of adding new app false. 
Is there another way to remove the title?

Here is where PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea in master page is.

```
<div id="contentBox" class="ms-pub-contentLayout ms-verticalAlignTop" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <a id="mainContent" name="mainContent" tabindex="-1"></a>
    <h1 id="pageContentTitle" class="ms-belltown-pageName ms-noWrap ms-dialogHidden">
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server"  >
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
              <SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb
                  runat="server"
                  RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
                  SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
                  WelcomePageUsesWebTitle="false">
                <PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
                  <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
                </PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
              </SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    </h1>
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" BlockElement="true" IsMainContent="true" runat="server" >
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" />
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to hide the PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea ContentPlaceHolder.

This PlaceHolder does not just hold the title, but certain other things as well.

Don't hide the placeholder in the master page. Rather create yourself a new Page Layout and hide whatever you dont want to see from the following within the PlaceHolder:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="3" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" id="TitleField" FieldName="Title"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePointWebControls:UIVersionedContent>
    <SharePointWebControls:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePointWebControls:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: When I add this code with or without Visible="false" it gives error. I didn't understand what you offer me to do. Why I have to put SharePointWebControls tags? There is nothing with SharePointWebControls tags.

Comment: The markup I shows below is not supposed to be placed in a Master page. This is markup for a Page Layout. Read more about Page Layouts/Master Pages here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms543497(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I created a new one and added what you wrote with Visible attribute. And I published it but nothing changed. So I found in a forum that says only add '<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" ></asp:Content>' into the page_layout but it didn't work too.. I read some forums and blogs but I can't find what I am missing.

Comment: I think the reason that my custom master page doesn't have a html page like oslo.master and oslo.html. Could it be the reason?

Comment: If you dont want to display the Page Title on any pages, then remove the following from your master page: <SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb
                  runat="server"
                  RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
                  SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
                  WelcomePageUsesWebTitle="false">
                <PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
                  <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
                </PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
              </SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>

Comment: Fox, please post this as an answer so you can have credit. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Or add this CSS to page

```
<style type="text/css">
#pageContentTitle {
display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This option worked well for me as I did not want to affect the layout of all pages, but only on specific pages.

Comment: for Online 2013 -  "#pageTitle {
display: none !important;
}"

Answer (score 2):

Add the below lines in page layout just above Publishing:EditModePanel tag.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function hidePageTitle() {
     var elem = document.getElementById('pageContentTitle');
     elem.style.display = 'none';
 }

 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hidePageTitle"); 
 </script>
```

Comment: This option worked well for me as I did not want to affect the layout of all pages, but only on specific pages.  In addition, I decided not to hide the title, but to change the title, so instead of elem.style.display = 'none'; I changed it to elem.innerHTML = "some value";

Comment: ok enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  In a Page Title field on a page in the /pages/ directory, we were getting the page file name appended to the front of the title:

[Page Name without extension] [Page Title].

In the case the page name was "Default.aspx" and the "Default" in front of the page title was driving us crazy. I spent quite a bit searching forums and MSDN, but nothing really worked.  In page code snippets wouldn't work (I presume due to some security issues).

I ended up working with Microsoft Support Technicians for about a day, and they helped me identify the tag that needs to be removed from the page layout page.

in the .aspx page:

```
<SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb runat="server" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider">          <PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
        <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
    </PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
</SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>
```

Removing that SPTitleBreadcrumb tag works.

If you are in an enviroment where your pagelayouts use a linked .html file (as was my case) this is the corresponding tag:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb
                    runat="server"
                    RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
                    SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
                CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider">-->
    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><span id="ctl00_DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea">Home</span><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
    <!--SPM:<PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
        <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server"/>-->
    <!--SPM:</PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>-->
```

Once this is removed (I used SharePoint Designer 2013), I needed to check the file in (which saves the changes and updates the .aspx file at the same time).  Then Publish it, and Approve it (due to Publishing Features being enabled on the site).  Refresh the page, and now the nuisance "Default" is gone from before the title and everything displays as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to hide the page title only on one page and found this article very helpfull - nice step by step instructions. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjjohn/2016/07/25/375/

Comment: You should not just paste link. You can add some explanation or part of blog you added as link